# image dimensions in javascript

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to get the dimensions of an image using javascript-- Mootools is the loaded library.

However, even though I get the image element with no problem, and see in the element's properties a valid width and height, the height value is always returned as 0 when I try to access the property.

Why?

```
window.addEvent("domready", function(){
    var thisImg = $$("img.myimgclass");

    console.dir(thisImg[0]); // prints all image data, including width AND height values

    var height = thisImg[0].height;
    var width = thisImg[0].width;

    console.log(height); // prints 0 even though thisImg shows a valid height set
    console.log(width); // prints valid width

});
```

Comment: Are you styles added in css or as attributes on the image?

Comment: your script gives correct values in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/FVaz8/), what does your markup look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call your code in the window load event, because even if the dom is built that doesn't mean the image is loaded. The console shows live objects, that is by the time you look at the console the image has loaded but when it was logged is hadn't loaded yet.

Comment: I didn't know that timing of the console call was different than the domready-- thanks for the tip! This has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the `height` and `width` *attributes* of the `img` tag, which likely are not set, though it's hard to say since you didn't include your HTML.

Comment: Well, I believe they are set, since like I said, when you `console.dir` the `thisImg[0]` img, they're both there in the data dumped. I'd be glad to know where I'm going wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

try image.naturalHeight and image.naturalWidth to get the actual size..